# Attempting to limit the results in SQL Server command

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsSearchResults" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:strConn %>" 
    <SelectCommand="SELECT StoreNumber, StoreName, Address, City, State, PostalCode, Phone, Email, Latitude, Longitude, SQRT(POWER(Latitude - @Latitude, 2) + POWER(Longitude - @Longitude, 2)) * 62.1371192 AS DistanceFromAddress 
                    FROM Stores 
                    WHERE (ABS(Latitude - @Latitude) &lt; 1.75) AND (ABS(Longitude - @Longitude) &lt; 1.75) 
                    ORDER BY DistanceFromAddress">
   <SelectParameters>
```

I want to limit the search results to the top 5 results. i have tried several different ways but to no avail. Yes I am a newbie but wanting to learn. I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your SQL command like this:

```
SELECT TOP 5 StoreNumber, StoreName, Address, City, 
State, PostalCode, Phone, Email, Latitude, Longitude, 
SQRT(POWER(Latitude - @Latitude, 2) 
+ POWER(Longitude - @Longitude, 2)) * 62.1371192 AS DistanceFromAddress 
FROM Stores WHERE (ABS(Latitude - @Latitude) &lt; 1.75) 
AND (ABS(Longitude - @Longitude) &lt; 1.75) 
ORDER BY DistanceFromAddress
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server uses `TOP` statement to limit query result.

In your case the query would be

```
SELECT TOP 5 StoreNumber, StoreName, Addres...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using TOP in your query:

```
SELECT top 5 StoreNumber, StoreName, Address, City, State, PostalCode, Phone, Email, 
Latitude, Longitude, SQRT(POWER(Latitude - @Latitude, 2) + POWER(Longitude - @Longitude, 2)) *
62.1371192 AS DistanceFromAddress FROM Stores WHERE (ABS(Latitude - @Latitude) &lt; 1.75) AND 
(ABS(Longitude - @Longitude) &lt; 1.75) ORDER BY DistanceFromAddress limit
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server **2012** allows you to use `FETCH OFFSET` in your `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT (all your columns) 
FROM Stores 
WHERE 
     (ABS(Latitude - @Latitude) &lt; 1.75) AND (ABS(Longitude - @Longitude) &lt; 1.75) 
ORDER BY DistanceFromAddress
OFFSET 100 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY;
```

This will *skip* the first 100 rows, and return 50 rows from there on. With this approach, you can select not only the top (n) rows - but any (n) rows somewhere in your result set - ideal for *paging* your results into pages of (n) rows each.

So if you want to top 5 rows only, use

```
....
ORDER BY DistanceFromAddress
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;
```